# Generating numbers and randomly displaying them

Tags: php

I want generate a list of numbers from 0000 to 9999. I would then like to take all the results and echo them out randomly. (not in order) How would I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$numbers = range(0,9999);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach($numbers as $number) {
   echo str_pad($number,4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT),'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To generate a list of 0000 to 9999, you can do something like this:

```
<?php

$array_list = array();
$end  =9999;
for($idx=0; $idx<=$end; $idx++)
{
    $array_list[$idx] = str_pad($idx, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
?>
```

To generate that list randomly, you can use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)():

```
<?php
for($idx=0; $idx<=9; $idx++)
{
    echo array_rand( $array_list );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Here..

```
$randarr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 9999; $i++) {
    array_push($randarr, $i);
}

shuffle($randarr);

foreach($randarr as $randval) {
    echo $randval . "\n";
}
```

Comment: No I mean I want to have every number echo out from 0000 to 9999, but not in order. It shouldn't be 0000, 0001, 0002. It should be 9328, 1283, 6839, etc.

Comment: Mike, the shuffle() function mixes the values of the array randomly. The list of numbers will no longer be in order.

Comment: @syrion, please look at the question. It's what he wants.

Comment: Ruel, I did. However, if you look at his comment on your answer, he thinks that your answer will emit the numbers in order.

Comment: @syrion: If you will look carefully on my answer, it's **edited**. He's referring to my earlier answer.

Comment: My apologies.  Your message saying that it was edited was not originally displayed in my list. Don't have a stroke. :D

Answer (score 1):

PHP does have some basic functions to generate this range:

```
$aRange = range(0, 9999);
shuffle($aRange);
print_r($aRange);
```

print the 4 digits output:

```
foreach($aRange as $number) {
    print str_pad($number, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out PHP's [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)() function.

You could do something like:

```
for ( $counter=0; $counter < 10000; $counter += 1) { 
    $rand=rand(0,9999); echo $rand."<br />";
}
```